# Vue v-text-field - previous value is automatically displayed when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

**The Vue input fields (v-text-field) automatically show the previous input when I click on the text field.**
Actually, I delete the value from all inputs with the blue button (which also creates additional random tables). The reset works, but why is the value displayed again?

What I tried: I used v-form to delete the value of all inputs with this.$refs.form.reset(); (see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#misc). That didn't solve the problem.

This is how it looks:
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9xGd.gif)

#### HTML

```
          <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
              ...
              <tbody>
                <tr :class="verb.ich">
                  <td>
                    <v-text-field label="ich"></v-text-field>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr :class="verb.du">
                  <td>
                    <v-text-field label="du"></v-text-field>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr :class="verb.er">
                  <td>
                    <v-text-field label="er/sie/es"></v-text-field>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                ...
                ...
              </tbody>
            </template>
          </v-simple-table>
          ...
          <v-btn @click="next"> Weiter </v-btn>
```

#### Method next():

```
next: function () {
      var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++) {
        allInputs[i].value = "";
        allInputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
...
}
```

#### Solution

(with the help of Michael Levý's answer)

- v-model

```
<td> 
 <v-text-field v-model="verb.val[0]"></v-text-field>
</td>
...
```

- reset value

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.verben.length; i++) {
  this.verben[i].val[0] = "";
  ...
}
```

- in each array

```
verben: [
  {
    val: ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-text-field` has some internal variable which saves the value when you are typing. Your `next()` method doesn't clear this value but only sets value of the rendered `<input>` control - when you click on the control, `v-text-field` is re-rendered and shows the value stored inside

Your `next` method is an example how not to work with form items in Vue. Vue is data driven. For each control you need a variable in `data()` section of your component and use `v-model` to bind the control to that variable.

Now when you want to change the value programmatically, you change the data in your component (not in the DOM)

[Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Vuetify form controls works same way - [examples](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#examples)

Comment: Thanks a lot! v-model was the solution. I've edited my question. If you have a better solution, I would be happy to hear from you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Using array is great solution....